# What is the most reliable ATSC TV tuner for use with OSX?

Tags: usb, peripheral

I'm looking for an OTA (over the air, eg. no cable) ATSC USB tuner to use with a Macbook. There appear to be a few options, all of which seem to have ugly hardware and buggy software. Does anyone have a recommendation? Elgato seems like the biggest manufacturer, but I'm reading mixed reviews.

I would primarily be using this in the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an Elgato EyeTV 250, and it works great. I think Elgato may be the best (if not the only) option.